# Python webframework для Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, веб-программирование, framework, веб-сервер, raspberry-pi

Уважаемые знатоки. 
Есть задача написать WebFramework для Raspberry. 
Назначение: управление роботами. Ну или подобным примитивом.
С чего начать чтобы свой сделать? Или есть ли что то подобно. 
Bubot смотрел, что то как то не понятно. 
Разбираться в чужом да ещё и не документированом, сложно. 
В интернете полно статей, нет уверенности подойдут ли они мне.

1. С raspberry работаю не первый день
2. Нужна информация о:
   -какие связки подойдут(Python с чем то)
   -какой web сервер лучше подойдёт 
   -ваш опыт

Comment: Я использовал `Flask` никаких проблем связанных именно с `Raspberry Pi` не обнаружилось.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Т.е. можно спокойно выполнять какие либо скрипты в связке с gpio?

Comment: Почему нет? Я `GPIO` напрямую не использовал, но активно использовал `SMBus`, все было хорошо.

Comment: I2c значит работает. А как с задержкой дела обстоят?

Comment: Я работал с медленными устройствами и малина не была узким местом, так что, точнее сказать не могу. Впрочем, были и проблемы https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/510 не знаю как сейчас, починили или нет.

Comment: Все же жду ещё варианты.

Comment: @БогданЛещенко "с чего начать" - очень размытый вопрос. На RPI есть i2c / gpio и байндинги на них под все подряд, от ноды до моно. и консольные байндинги под те языки, где не-консольных - нет. Начните с покупки малинки, и когда будут конкретные вопросы - приносите их сюда.

Comment: Если бы вы просмотрели предыдущие комментарии, то поняли что Я не новичок в raspberry. Активно использую её. Вот и встал вопрос о web. Так как аналоговые кнопки это прошлый век.

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит воспринимать линейку Raspberry как нечто особенное дикое и не поддающееся дрессировки (вроде ОС Tizen). На Raspberry 2B вы спокойно ставите Windows 10,JVM (начиная с JDK 8u51) да и почти все что угодно. Так что относитесь к поставленной задаче как к разработке обычного десктопного приложения.И в дополнение [офф.ресурс](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) богат примерами и сообщество не маленькое.

Удачи

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Признаю. Офф.сайт не заглянул. Посмотрю что там есть. Но Ваш ответ не совсем то что Я хотел получить. Я не новичок в Raspberry. По это причине и хочу что то своё.

Comment: Ясно.Тогда это я не разобрался в сути вопроса.[Тут](https://github.com/DexterInd/GoPiGo) находиться достаточно интересное решение (не без Arduino  :) ) здесь же [список](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=raspberry+robot&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults) альтернатив

Comment: Очень интересно. Изучу. Спасибо.